# defining a higher dimensional array without using extra memory

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'd like to define a higher dimensional array in terms of a lower dimensional array, without taking up extra storage space. I was wondering if this is possible. I think I have a solution using broadcasting (see below), but I think it will take up extra storage space.

```
aa=np.arange(2).reshape(2,1)
bb=np.zeros(10).reshape(5,2,1)
bb+=aa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.broadcast_to`

```
import numpy as np
import sys
 
aa=np.arange(2).reshape(2,1)                                                                                                                                            
bb=np.zeros((50,2,1))
bb+=aa
 
cc = np.broadcast_to(aa[None],bb.shape)
(cc == bb).all()
# True
 
sys.getsizeof(bb)
# 928
sys.getsizeof(cc)
# 128
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the same array with a single line of code:

```
>>> np.array([0,1]*5).reshape(5,2,1)
array([[[0],
        [1]],

       [[0],
        [1]],

       [[0],
        [1]],

       [[0],
        [1]],

       [[0],
        [1]]])
```